# Configuring Window Service Base Path and read environment variables

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, self-hosting

I've created a Windows Service with .Net Core 2.2 utilizing Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting and a console application.  I have used ConfigurationBuilder
to include json configuration services like so:

```
string environment = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");    
new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{environment}.json", optional: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables()
            .Build();
```

When debugging in Visual Studio, the base path is being correctly set to the Current directory.  The environment variable 'ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT' is set as both a user and system level, and the configuration files are properly recognized and used.
However, when I install as a Windows Service, the base path becomes C:\Windows\system32, and I haven't gotten the environment variables call to work yet.  I could easily just hard code the base path and put my configuration files there, but I lose flexibility. I also need to be able to read the configuration file values inside a method inside an event-bound process.

Is there some way to read the environment variables to set basepath and read the configuration files within an event bound method?

Comment: I don't get the usage of the service you're deploying, but environment variables are supposed to help you getting/accessing programs, paths and so on. In a nutshell we could say they're "global variables". Do you want to place some files in a safe and "user dependant" account/path or so?

Comment: @Gonzo345, System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT") is not returning the user or system value that is set when in a Windows Service.  If I can get that, then I will have an easily solution to SetBasePath().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can easily use environment variables. Example

```
var profilePath = Configuration<string>["PROFILEPATH"]
```

will give you ProfilePath

But Please keep in mind that your service works  under one of the System User which is why it's base path refers to `c:\Windows\System32`

Comment: yes I understand - if I can get the GetEnvironmentVariable working, I can set BasePath to the environment variable and solve my issues.

Comment: Ok, so the environment problem turned out to be an issue with delayed response from my virtual box.   The environment can now be read and I can set the profile.  Thanks for this though!